# Hardcoded value to user input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to change a hard coded input (ContactInterval) to allow a user to choose how much time to put in. Currently it is set to 20 minutes.

Here is how the lock is created:
And the ContactInterval is hard coded in the Echo.Common.Services.LockManagerServices

```
public Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem GetLock(Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem.LockType lockType, int entityId, int userId, string userName, string phoneNumber)
{
    Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem theLock = new Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem();

    try
    {
        Echo.Common.Services.LockManagerServices lockManagerServices = new Echo.Common.Services.LockManagerServices();
        Echo.Common.Services.LockItem returnedLock = lockManagerServices.GetLock((Echo.Common.Services.LockType)lockType, entityId, userId, userName, phoneNumber);
        theLock.UserId = returnedLock.UserId;
        theLock.UserName = returnedLock.UserName;
        theLock.PhoneNumber = returnedLock.PhoneNumber;
        theLock.ExpireSecs = returnedLock.ExpireSecs;
        theLock.ContactInterval = returnedLock.ContactInterval;
        int respondsID = (int)returnedLock.ResponseId;
        theLock.ResponseId = (LockItem.LockResponse)respondsID;
    }
    catch
    {
        theLock.ResponseId = LockItem.LockResponse.ERROR;
    }
    return theLock;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: Is `ContactInterval` a `System.TimeSpan`? If so, you can `.TryParse()` or `.TryParseExact()` your user input to the desired `TimeSpan`.

Comment: how is the communicating with the user?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to overload the method:

```
public Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem GetLock(Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem.LockType lockType, int entityId, int userId, string userName, string phoneNumber, ContactInterval contactInterval = null)
{
    Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem theLock = new Echo.Common.Business.LockingManager.LockItem();

    try
    {
        Echo.Common.Services.LockManagerServices lockManagerServices = new Echo.Common.Services.LockManagerServices();
        Echo.Common.Services.LockItem returnedLock = lockManagerServices.GetLock((Echo.Common.Services.LockType)lockType, entityId, userId, userName, phoneNumber);
        theLock.UserId = returnedLock.UserId;
        theLock.UserName = returnedLock.UserName;
        theLock.PhoneNumber = returnedLock.PhoneNumber;
        theLock.ExpireSecs = returnedLock.ExpireSecs;
        // check if contactInterval is null, if not, use it, otherwise use default from returnedLock
        theLock.ContactInterval = (contactInterval != null) ? contactInterval : returnedLock.ContactInterval;
        int respondsID = (int)returnedLock.ResponseId;
        theLock.ResponseId = (LockItem.LockResponse)respondsID;
    }
    catch
    {
        theLock.ResponseId = LockItem.LockResponse.ERROR;
    }
    return theLock;
}
```

This of course assumes that ContactInterval is its own type. Otherwise, you just pass the type it is, i.e.: `int`, `double`, `datetime`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Tried some of your suggestions but just found out that the Services is going to need to be bypassed since it is untouchable for me. Didn't realize that when the Lock expired that it would automatically create a new one based on values in the Service.